# localhost in postfix's mydestination

Tags: postfix

I noticed that many tutorials on the web specify the `mydestination` variable of postfix like this:

```
mydestination = localhost, localhost.myhostname, myhostname, mydomain1.com, mydomain2.com
```

Note: `myhostname` is the name postfix uses in `HELO`.
However this would allow an external client to send an email to user@localhost. Of course only if `user` is a valid username and postfix' restrictions (like `reject_non_fqdn_recipient`) are not used.

Since I want to accept mails only for `mydomain1.com` and `mydomain2.com` I changed the line at my server to:

```
mydestination = mydomain1.com, mydomain2.com
```

This works for external mail and even for local mails, where only the receiver-username without domain is used (due to the correct domain `mydomain1.com` in `/etc/mailname`).

Now I wonder whether the absence of `localhost` etc. in `mydestination` can cause any problems or if my configuration is fine.

Comment: System generated emails like cronjob emails or other system notifications are sent to usually root@localhost or root@hostname. Those emails may fail to reach destination and stay in the queue.

Comment: Why do you want to remove localhost? You can setup your custom `mydestination` for port 25 if you want.

Comment: @Tutul: So it's probably best to add `localhost` and `myhostname` back to `mydestination`. But how can I prevent that an external MTA can send eMail to, for example, root@myhostname? (In my case `myhostname` ist a FQDN)

Comment: You can use check_recipient_access restriction in smtpd_recipient_restrictions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reject mail for specific recipient, put
in main.cf:

`smtpd_recipient_restrictions =     permit_my networks,
   reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
   reject_unauth_destination,
   check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/recipient_reject`

In /etc/postfix/recipient_reject:

`root@host.example.com REJECT`

Comment: I now use `smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination, reject_non_fqdn_recipient, check_recipient_access regexp:/etc/postfix/recipient_reject` and a regexp to block all `@localhost`-addresses, not just root. However sending emails to localhost using the `mail` command on the server works fine. Nice!